# How write special character (é, è) with StreamWriter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, special-characters, streamwriter.write

My problem : I want to write datas with a StreamWriter (my String contains letters é and è) but it doesn't work. Without this letters, it works.

The error : Cannot close the stream

My code :

```
 string postString = "id=" + sIdTransaction + "&nom=" + sNom + "&prenom=" + sPrenom + "&email=" + sEmail + "&adresse.rue=" + sRue + "&adresse.codePostal=" + sCodePostal + "&adresse.ville=" + sVille;
string sIdContractant = "";
Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(postString);
byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso, utfBytes);
postString = iso.GetString(isoBytes);

string sUrlAuth = "https://test.contralia.fr/Contralia/api/transactions/" + sIdTransaction + "/contractant/";
HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreationRequete(sUrlAuth);
webRequest.ContentLength = postString.Length;


StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
requestWriter.Write(postString);
requestWriter.Close();
```

adresse.Ville = Fercé (problem with this é)
How can I resolve this problem please ? 
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure about this line: Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"); ? Shouldn't it be "iso-8859-1"?

Comment: It was my fisrt idea but it's not the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the encoding for the StreamWriter:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream(), encoding)
```

Try this, I hope it helps. It worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code by this :

```
string postString = "id=" + sIdTransaction + "&nom=" + sNom + "&prenom=" + sPrenom + "&email=" + sEmail + "&adresse.rue=" + sRue + "&adresse.codePostal=" + sCodePostal + "&adresse.ville=" + sVille;
string sIdContractant = "";
Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(postString);
byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso, utfBytes);
postString = iso.GetString(isoBytes);

string sUrlAuth = "https://test.contralia.fr/Contralia/api/transactions/" + sIdTransaction + "/contractant/";
HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreationRequete(sUrlAuth);
webRequest.ContentLength = postString.Length;


StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream(), iso);
requestWriter.Write(postString);
requestWriter.Close();
```

i just changer, in your 11th line, `StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());`
 by 
`StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream(), iso);`